# How to make history.pushstate() actually existing on the Internet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-history

I'm making a poll website and I'm trying to figure out how [Straw Poll](https://www.strawpoll.me/%22Straw%20Poll%22) did it...

So let's take it as a example:

After create_poll form is submitted, user will be redirected to a new link looks like this: https://www.strawpoll.me/15147968. My thought was that after a poll is created, a new row is inserted to database, and 15147968 or whatever after "/" is a new poll id.

So basically my solution is using AJAX to insert and fetch the new id from database, then use `window.location.hash` append the number after `#` tag, but I still can't figure out **how to change `#` to `/`**?

Since I want to make this link shareable, I don't think I can use `history.pushstate()` **unless there is some way to make it not only exist in history?** And also, I can't use `location.assign(location.href.replace('#', "/"))` because it disables my javascript and stylesheet somehow. I'm also open to any other ways to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thats a serverside thing. If you want the history entry to be shareable, the server must return a valid response when someone requests that url.

Comment: @JonasW. Can you explain more on that?